# Cant' reach https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send endpoint (?)

Tags: php, sendgrid

I've got an issue with sending e-mails with PHP using Sendgrid - I try to send the simpliest e-mail, I get 202 status, but no e-mails are delivered.

I've already contacted with SendGrid support team to confirm that my API KEY is valid and has correct permissions.

I use:

```
- PHP 7.3.0
- Composer 1.8.3
```

This is my composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "sendgrid/sendgrid": "^7.3",
    "sendgrid/php-http-client": "~3.9.6"
  }
}
```

I've produced the simplest test endpoint to send an e-mail. It's in here -> http://konfiguratorszkolen.pl/send-email/test.php

The code in this PHP looks this:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("testemail1@gmail.com", "Example User");
$email->setSubject("Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("testemail2@gmail.com", "Example User");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid("MyValidAPIKey");
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
?>
```

Sendgrid support team says that I don't send POST request to the https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send endpoint. But shouldn't $response = $sendgrid->send($email); do that job?

What might be the issue? How can I reach the endpoint?

I want to add, that this kind of code worked perfectly in May. It stopped a few weeks ago. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you check in spam emails?

Comment: You're pretending that SendGrid is GMail, but it is not. I haven't used SendGrid for a long time, but don't you need to send on behalf of your own domain? See "Settings", "Sender Authentication". And you're also sending to GMail, that's the worst possible place to send email to.

Comment: @Nux Yes, I've checked it - it's empty

Comment: @KIKOSoftware -> It doesn't work at any e-mail provider. Gmail is only an example. But You may be right it has someting to do with sender authentication. But it is very strange, because it worked perfect a few weeks before and now I can see that my domain authentication has 'failed' status...

I'm using SendGrid, because in my final project, I've got a form that has to send two e-mails: to the administrator and to the user (depends on what e-mail address is provided in the form)